# Анализатор спектра

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

Всем привет. Мне нужен анализатор спектра в реальном времени как в звуковых плеерах. На языке python. Код для чтение wav файла и fft готов, но не понимаю как строить "столбики звука". Пробовал через matplotlib. Нечего не вышло. Заранее спасибо.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.fftpack import fft

#Указываем путь до аудио файла
myAudio = "22.wav"

#Чтение файла и получение частоты дискретизации и звукового объект
samplingFreq, mySound = wavfile.read(myAudio)

#Проверяем является ли wave-файл 16-битным или 32-битным. (24 бит не 
#поддерживается)
mySoundDataType = mySound.dtype

#Мы можем преобразовать наш звуковой массив в значения с плавающей запятой в 
#диапазоне от -1 до 1 следующим образом

mySound = mySound / (2.**15)

#Проверим точки отсчета и звуковой канал для двух каналов или для моноканала

mySoundShape = mySound.shape
samplePoints = float(mySound.shape[0])

#Получим продолжительность звукового файла
signalDuration = mySound.shape[0] / samplingFreq

#Если два канала, то выберем только один кана
mySoundOneChannel = mySound[:,0]
#График частотного содержания
#Мы можем получить частоту из амплитуды и времени с помощью БПФ, быстрого 
#алгоритма преобразования Фурье
#Получим длину моего массива звуковых объектов
mySoundLength = len(mySound)

#Возьмем преобразование Фурье для данной точки отсчета
fftArray = fft(mySoundOneChannel)

numUniquePoints = int(numpy.ceil((mySoundLength + 1) / 2.0))
fftArray = fftArray[0:numUniquePoints]

#БПФ содержит как величину, так и фазу и задается комплексными числами в 
#формате действительных + мнимых частей (a + ib).
#Принимая абсолютное значение, мы получаем только действительную часть.

fftArray = abs(fftArray)

#Масштабируйте массив fft по длине точек выборки, чтобы величина не зависела 
#отдлина сигнала или его частота дискретизации

fftArray = fftArray / float(mySoundLength)

#БПФ имеет как положительную, так и отрицательную информацию. Площадь 
#возводим в квадрат, чтобы получить только положительные значения
fftArray = fftArray **2

if mySoundLength % 2 > 0: #у нас есть нечетное число точек в FFT
         fftArray[1:len(fftArray)] = fftArray[1:len(fftArray)] * 2

else: #У нас есть чётное количество точек в БПФ
         fftArray[1:len(fftArray) -1] = fftArray[1:len(fftArray) -1] * 2

freqArray = numpy.arange(0, numUniquePoints, 1.0) * (samplingFreq / mySoundLength)
```

Побывал вот так (код ниже) он строит сразу все целиком. А мне нужно в реальном времени опять же как в музыкальных плеерах.

```
plt.plot(freqArray/1000, 10 * numpy.log10 (fftArray))
plt.xlabel('Частота (Khz)')
plt.ylabel('Мощность (dB)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вместо

```
plt.plot(freqArray/1000, 10 * numpy.log10 (fftArray))
```

написать так:

```
plt.plot(freqArray[0:99]/1000, 10 * numpy.log10 (fftArray))
```

то будут обработаны первые 100 отсчётов. Организуйте "протяжку" этого окна [0:99] по времени и будет Вам картинка в реальном времени.

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку.    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1361,) and (136141,) При введение [0:13614] он строит "спектр" полностью.

Comment: @MyBigPony3 - Сделайте аналогичный срез для *fftArray* - что бы размерности по X и Y совпадали.